# Error for git submodule in Gitlab CI runner - "fatal: destination path already exists and is not an empty directory."

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-submodules, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to include a submodule into my GitLab repository. It works just fine locally, but my build pipeline fails. According to [this docs entry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html), all I should do is use relative url and set up the `GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY`, but it doesn't really work.

My `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "res/submoduleName"]
    path = res/submoduleName
    url = ../submoduleName.git
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

integration-test:
  # ...
```

I get the following error in my Pipeline shell:

```
Updating/initializing submodules recursively...
Submodule 'res/submoduleName' (https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/mainProjectName/submoduleName.git) registered for path 'res/submoduleName'
fatal: destination path '/builds/_oBZKNaH/0/mainProjectName/mainProjectName/res/submoduleName' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/mainProjectName/submoduleName.git' into submodule path '/builds/_oBZKNaH/0/mainProjectName/mainProjectName/res/submoduleName' failed
Failed to clone 'res/submoduleName'. Retry scheduled
fatal: destination path '/builds/_oBZKNaH/0/mainProjectName/mainProjectName/res/submoduleName' already exists and is not an empty directory.
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/mainProjectName/submoduleName.git' into submodule path '/builds/_oBZKNaH/0/mainProjectName/mainProjectName/res/submoduleName' failed
Failed to clone 'res/submoduleName' a second time, aborting
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the path `res/submoduleName` an existing folder with contents prior to your decision to use a submodule on that path? If yes, then you need to remove that folder first from both local and remote before you can register the path as a submodule path.

Comment: No, there was never such folder prior to adding a submodule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was misleading. The folder was empty, but GitLab runner did not have the permissions to write into it. I solved the problem by adding `- chmod -R 777 res` to [before_script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) of my job.

Comment: No idea why, but this works. We have two submodules, parent folders from those submodules are different, but they have the same permissions. One of those submodules works, and the other did not (only like 80% of the time). This fixed our issue.